# Concurrency - write a program in which multiple threads add the same amount of elements to list

Tags: java, multithreading, reflection, concurrency

So I am supposed to write a program, in which multiple threads add some number of items to a list. I was given two interfaces that I should implement. The number added is a sum of two previous numbers added (like Fibonacci series)

```
public interface Main
{
    List<Integer> sum(int count, int threadCount, int firstElement, int secondElement);
}
```

and

```
public interface Sum extends Runnable
{
    //how many elements each thread should add
    int getHowMany();

    List<Integer> getList();
}
```

So I thought of doing it this way: I create a class DefaultSum, which implements Sum interface, implement methods from it, and in the run() method I would call a method actually adding elements to list. 
This is my DefaultSum class

```
public class DefaultSum implements Sum {
    DefaultMain main = new DefaultMain();

    DefaultSum() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int count = getHowMany();
        List<Integer> list = getList();

        int firstElement = list.get(list.size() - 2).intValue();
        int secondElement = list.get(list.size() - 1).intValue();
        int j = 2;
        while (j < count) {
            int adder = firstElement + secondElement;
            list.add(adder);
            System.out.println(list);
            firstElement = secondElement;
            secondElement = adder;
            if (j == count) {
                notifyAll();
            }
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println(list);

    }

    @Override
    public int getHowMany() {

        try {
            Field[] fields = DefaultMain.class.getFields();
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                Object val = fields[i].get(main);
                if (fields[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("count")) {
                    int number = (Integer) val;
                    return number;

                }
            }

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> getList() {

        try {
            Field[] fields = DefaultMain.class.getFields();
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                Object val = fields[i].get(main);
                if (fields[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("list")) {

                    return (List<Integer>) val;
                }
            }

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And my main class, DefaultMain, where the number of items added is given and user can decide how many threads he wants to work on this list.

```
public class DefaultMain implements Main {
    static int firstElement = 0;
    static int secondElement = 1;
    static int count = 10;
    public static List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(lista);
    static int threadCount;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        list.add(firstElement);
        list.add(secondElement);

        System.out.println("how many threads");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        threadCount = sc.nextInt();

        Main exa = new DefaultMain();
        exa.sum(count, threadCount, firstElement, secondElement);

    }

    @Override
    public  List<Integer> sum(int count, int threadCount, int firstElement, int secondElement) {

        synchronized(this.list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < DefaultMain.threadCount; i++) {

            new Thread(new DefaultSum()).start();

        }
        return list;
    }
}}
```

I tried running this program multiple times, however, it seems that the list is not updated after first two elements are added. Seems that methods getHowMany() and getList() work fine, I'm not sure what could be wrong, I'll appreciate any answer, this problem has been bugging me for some time now.

Edit: I'll paste what I get in console
Edit2: tried changing some bits, but it does not work at all.

```
how many threads
4
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
```

Comment: Why are you using Reflection to read the field of `DefaultMain`? Why are you using *case insensitive* comparison for accessing these fields? Why are these fields declared `static`? Why are you calling `notifyAll()`? This method would throw an exception, the way you use it, but due to the `if (j == count)` condition withing a `while (j < count)` loop, it will never be called anyway.

Comment: @Holger          Fields are declared static because I could not use the method sum in main, reflection is used because I thought it would be good method to obtaingl the fields I need, but I guess somehing like returning main.list, or main.count would work.

Comment: So your code creates even *two* objects of `DefaultMain` and is not using either, because everything is stored in `static` fields. Further, “I thought it would be good method…”, is not an explanation at all. Why did you think it was a good method to write complicated and error prone code, instead of just accessing the fields? Yes, just using `main.list` and `main.count` would work and even eliminate your question’s problem, though, since the fields are `static`, using `main` for accessing them distracts from the reality, as you are actually accessing `DefaultMain.list` and `DefaultMain.count`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I changed the code and now it works fine. As for the static keyword, I had multiple warnings about not making static reference to a non static object,   I had wrong approach and wanted to deal with this program quickly so I left it this way.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to create a single thread `Executor` and then from any thread call `execute()` with the operations you need to do on the list in a `Runnable` provided as the only parameter. Here is what it looks like with a lambda.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

service.execute(() -> {
    int size = list.size();
    list.add(list.get(size - 1) + list.get(size - 2));
});
```

As the JavaDoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) states "Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an unbounded queue...Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time."

Comment: Yes, I was told that the problem is kind of similiar to Readers-Writers problem, so your explanation is really good, however, I changed the list to the Collections.synchronized(List) but it still doesnt work properly, I edited my post and pasted the output that console shows me. Sorry for bothering, but I'm not sure how make it work out

Comment: What does "work on the List" mean? The `synchronizedList()` method will give you an object that ensures that any _single operation_ will not corrupt the underlying list, but that completely ignores what "thread safe" might mean to the application. More often than not, an application requires some _sequence_ of operations, on a list (and maybe on other objects as well) to be seen as happening atomically by other threads. Also note, Javadoc for `synchronizedList()` says, "It is imperative that the user _manually synchronize_ on the returned list when iterating over it." (emphasis, mine.)

Comment: I tried synchronizing it manually but it does not seem to work. The whole "adding to list" code doesnt happen at all when running the program

Comment: @krysznys i changed my answer. this should do it for you. My apologizes for mistakenly giving you erroneous information about iteration on a synchronizedList. It would have still required getting "work on the list" in some form like in the new answer above anyway.

Comment: @SolomonSlow i see that you are a pro at stackoverflow. i am new. please let me know, if it is better to make me, who made a mistake, feel very intimidated by your strong response, or to answer the question AND help me realize my mistake with kinder words. thank you for introducing me to stackoverflow with your grace.